# Assembling and Linking gcc generated assembly on Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, gcc, assembly

If I have the following C Code

```
int main()
{
    return 77;
}
```

I can generate asm code with the -S option on clang to get the following (Intel syntax)

```
$clang -O0 -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel main.c -S
```

the code then is

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .globl  _main
    .align  4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    push    RBP
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp3:
    .cfi_offset rbp, -16
    mov RBP, RSP
Ltmp4:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register rbp
    mov EAX, 77
    mov DWORD PTR [RBP - 4], 0
    pop RBP
    ret
    .cfi_endproc


.subsections_via_symbols
```

However neither as, gas or nasm will generate an object file to link with ld... does clang or gcc generate actual good "ready to go" asm? gcc's default assembler is gas (which isn't even installed on mac os x...? isn't it the same for clang).

So how do I manually assemble the asm code and then link it?

Comment: How are you getting Intel syntax from the Mac GCC? `man gcc` explicitly says that `-masm=intel` is not supported on Darwin.

Comment: So, you're not using GCC, you're using clang. Well, there's your problem.

Comment: Nothing like lies to make questions easier to answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes, gcc generates correct assembly code.
2. It's just `as`.
3. You should be able to assemble it with `as` and link with `ld`:

   ```
   as -o example.o example.s
   ld -macosx_version_min 10.8.0 -o example example.o -lSystem
   ```

   or, probably more easily, by using `gcc` or `clang` as the frontend:

   ```
   cc -o example example.s
   ```

Edit:  Complete working example:

```
$ cat example.c 
int main()
{
    return 77;
}
$ gcc -S example.c -o example.s
$ as -o example.o example.s
$ ld -macosx_version_min 10.8.0 -o example example.o -lSystem
$ ./example 
$ echo $?
77
```

OK, since you're using clang, you might want to be using its assembler, too.  Mixing & matching toolchains usually ends in tears:

```
$ clang -cc1as -filetype obj -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel -o example.o example.s
$ ld -macosx_version_min 10.8.0 -o example example.o -lSystem
```

Comment: as doesn't work with error

$ gcc main.s

main.s:5:Unknown pseudo-op: .cfi_startproc
... [bunch of other errors]

cc didn't work with error

$ cc -o example.o main.s
main.s:11:14: error: invalid register name
 .cfi_offset rbp, -16
             ^~~~

Comment: Then you didn't use the system gcc to generate the assembly. I just tested your exact code here.  Are you trying to mix & match toolchains?

Comment: Oh - I just reread your question.  Intel syntax is almost certainly not going to work with apple's assembler.  In a quick test here, Apple's GCC didn't even accept `-masm=intel` as a flag, so you must be doing something strange.

Comment: I thought I used gcc turns out yes I tried with gcc and it wouldn't generated intel assembly and I used clang which did.

Comment: @Zimm3r: this is not a good way to write a question. Next time, please include the explicit command(s) you use.

Comment: It worth pointing out that according to GCC(1), "In Apple's version of GCC, both cc and gcc are actually symbolic links to the llvm-gcc compiler." which turns out to be clang.

Comment: Thanks, @hyh. That's new since this answer, I think.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using clang, why not compile it with clang instead of gcc?

```
clang main.s -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel -o main
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling gcc with the .s file.

Comment: Didn't work 
$ gcc main.s
main.s:5:Unknown pseudo-op: .cfi_startproc
... [bunch of other errors]

Comment: Your .s file was probably not created by gcc then. Perhaps you were using a different compiler?

Comment: Ya I remembered I finally got clang to output intel syntax and gcc wouldn't.